# Laravel 5 .env.travis file is ignored

Tags: travis-ci, laravel-5

I created a new file for Travis CI environment that looks like this

**.env.travis**

```
APP_ENV=travis 
APP_DEBUG=true 
APP_KEY=SomeRandomString

DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
DB_DATABASE=travis
DB_USERNAME=travis
DB_PASSWORD=

CACHE_DRIVER=file
SESSION_DRIVER=file
```

And this env file seems to be ignored.

I tested with creating a new console class with this content

```
public function fire()
{
    //
    echo env('APP_ENV') ."\n";
    echo "Database ". env('DB_DATABASE') ."\n";
    echo "Username ". env('DB_USERNAME') ."\n";
}
```

When I run the command I get this output

```
➤ ./artisan env:database --env=travis
local
Database forge
Username forge
```

Do you know why the environment file is ignored?

Comment: Laravel 5 differs from Laravel 4 in how .env files work. Now, you don't do .env.somename any longer. Instead, you have one .env file where you put your environment variables. I'm honestly not sure how to solve that for Travis, save for setting up an entire separate copy.

Comment: I need to find a way to make this work. Is there a repository with travis ci configurations somewhere?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a way to make the travis env file be used.

It's a bit of a hack, but this way you can have your .env file separate fron the .env.travis file

Just run the copy command to overwrite the **.env** file with your **.env.travis** file in the **.travis.yml** config

```
before_script:
    - cp .env.travis .env
```

Answer (score 0):

If anyone like me is here to see a full config file to copy past it, here's a full travis config file that works well with Laravel 5.*

**.travis.yml**

```
language: php

php:
  - 5.5.9
  - 5.6
  - 7.0
  - hhvm

matrix:
    allow_failures:
        - php: hhvm

before_script:
- cp .env.travis .env
- mysql -e 'create database homestead;'
- composer self-update
- composer install --prefer-source --no-interaction --dev
- php artisan migrate
- php artisan db:seed

script: vendor/bin/phpunit
```

make sure you have **.env.travis**